# Add Google Analytics to Angular 5 project with different environments

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

I am using Angular 5 and want to add Google Analytics.

There's a number of tutorials on this already such as:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/integrating-google-analytics-with-angular-2
- https://codeburst.io/using-google-analytics-with-angular-25c93bffaa18

All the tutorials I've seen requires adding the following code to index.html:

**index.html**

```html
...
<app-root></app-root>
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-109919601-1', 'auto'); // add your tracking ID here. ISSUE HERE!
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
...
```

The problem is the line:

```
ga('create', 'UA-109919601-1', 'auto');
```

I want to use a different tracking code depending what environment I am in.
How can I do this?

Some solutions suggest adding this code within the Angular code like this:

```js
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">// ProductionAnalyticsCodeHere</script>');
} else if (environment.staging) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">// StagingAnalyticsCodeHere</script>');
}
```

The issue with that solution is that Google Analytics is not run as quickly, affecting the load time analytics.

Comment: i think you should try this solution https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-399888807

Comment: @Nirali Patel Unfortunately that is Angular 6.

Answer (score 2):

**index.html**

Comment out the following lines:

```js
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto'); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**app.component.ts**

Add the tracking ID to your `environment.ts` files as `gaTrackingId`.

Put the following code in your constructor:

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    (<any>window).ga('create', environment.gaTrackingId, 'auto');
    (<any>window).ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
    (<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
});
```